# Is there any provison to playback exoplayer video where we left when we again launch video

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I can save time where I left but how I can play the video again where I have left earlier in Exoplayer?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [ExoPlayer documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#seekTo-long-)

> **seekTo**
>
> ```
> void seekTo​(long positionMs)
> ```
>
> Seeks to a position specified in milliseconds in the current window.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `positionMs` - The seek position in the current window, or
> `C.TIME_UNSET` to seek to the window's default position.

Here is the solution:

```
// playbackPositionMs is the time you saved where you left before
exoPlayer.seekTo(playbackPositionMs);
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```